# create table with serial primary key

Tags: postgresql, primary-key, create-table, jupyterhub

My question is about running CREATE TABLE with a SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, but keep getting errors.  Even after I correct the code based on the errors. the errors persist.  Any help is appreciated.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS nm_land_grants;
CREATE TABLE nm_land_grants (
    ID SERIAL, land_grant INT,  
    area REAL, perimeter REAL,
    grant_name VARCHAR(255), 
    land_grant INT, land_gra_1 INT,
    survey_app DATE, grant_conf DATE
    CONSTRAINT pk_nm_land_grants
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

The error I'm getting is as follows:

```
Done.
(psycopg2.ProgrammingError) syntax error at or near "("
LINE 6:     PRIMARY KEY (ID)
                    ^
 [SQL: 'CREATE TABLE nm_land_grants (\n    ID SERIAL, land_grant INT,  area 
REAL, perimeter REAL,\n    grant_name VARCHAR(255), land_grant INT, 
land_gra_1 INT,\n    survey_app DATE, grant_conf DATE\n    CONSTRAINT 
pk_nm_land_grants\n    PRIMARY KEY (ID)\n);']
```

Comment: you're missing commas after DATE and pk_nm_land_grants

Comment: @GuyL - I added the commas, and the error now says: `(psycopg2.ProgrammingError) syntax error at or near ","
LINE 5:     CONSTRAINT pk_nm_land_grants,`
                                                                         ^

Comment: @GuyL You are on the right track, but only the first of the commas you suggest is correct.

Comment: @knuckles98 you missed the error itself, the line broke

Comment: @laurenz-albe @guyl - Thank you!  I kept the first comma (after `grant_conf DATE`) and removed the last comma (after `pk_nm_land_grants`)